# Should the logistic regression equation always result in a value between 0 and 1?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I am a medical scientist but an amateur statistician (not even amateur). I have a simple question. Here is the output from a logistic regression examining a number of variables which may predict if a doctor will perform a biopsy in a patient or not. So the dependent variable is "biopsy or not". It's been run in 24240 doctor-patient consultation.

[image]

What I want to do is evaluate the relationship between these variables and biopsy decisions in each INDIVIDUAL doctor-patient consultation using the logistic regression equation and these coefficients.

My primary question is:

If apply:

```
    age * -.02742 + dlco * 0.0053058 + pioped_intermediate * 1.244477 + pioped_ipf_intermediate * 0.172851 + .6047641
```

to an individual doctor-patient consultation, am I correct in thinking I should get a result between 0 and 1? If I am getting values that range from -1.6 to +1.5 does that indicate there is a mistake in my calculations?

I hope this makes sense (and its acceptable to upload a screenshot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Your linear function could return any real value. You are supposed to put that value into the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit) to get a probability value between 0 and 1. That's really the whole trick of logistic regression: to create a mapping between a scale with range $[0, 1]$ and range $[-\infty,+\infty]$.

Comment: Thanks, David - are you saying the equation is the linear function and that value goes into Log(p/1-p)?

Comment: It actually goes into the inverse function of that: exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))

Comment: Almost. Your expression is the linear function, and its value goes into the _logistic_ function $p = e^t/(e^t +1)$, which the inverse of the _logit_ function $t = \ln(p / (1-p))$.

Comment: Many thanks - this works as I expected. Sorry for the ridiculously basic question.

Comment: Last thing; is there a convention on what constitutes a 1 versus a 0. i.e is 0.5 and above consider a 1 and below 0.5 considered a 0? Or is there some validated scale which includes an "indeterminate band"?

Comment: No. What there is is a way to assign an error bar or confidence interval to your estimated p, based on the covariances between your linear parameters. It's a bit too complicated to explain in a comment, but that is really what you want to do.

Comment: You are at liberty to put your cut-off anywhere you want depending on the costs and benefits of the right and wrong decisions (true, false positives, true, false negatives). In the absence of that information 0.5 is conventional.